# Getting Scikit-Learn RandomForestClassifier to output Top N results

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, prediction, random-forest

I'd like to see the top N results for a RandomForestClassifier prediction, ordered by descending probability.

The answer may be predict_proba, but I have no idea how to interpret the results.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Top N of what? RFC is a binary classifier, it predicts probability that an observation belongs to the positive class. If you want to find most probable samples, it's completely independent of sklearn, you just sort probabilities.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're right to use `predict_proba`. Use [`np.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) to interpret the results:

```
p = rfc.predict_proba(X)
n = 3
top_n = np.argsort(p)[:,:-n-1:-1]
```

Comment: If your classes are integers from 0 to n_classes ;) otherwise you need to use ``rfc.classes_[top_n]``